# Unable to animate Font Awesome Icon using Vivus

Tags: jquery, svg, font-awesome, vivus

I'm trying to get a font awesome icon to be drawn onDocumentReady, however I'm having some issues with it.

The library that came to my mind is [Vivus](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/). There's a library for connecting Font Awesome and Vivus aswell: [FontAnimate](https://github.com/innovato/fontanimate).

I thought easy game, but I can't seem to fill the icons I'm drawing.
Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/m1og17yz/

The fill is happening before the animation ends and the fill isn't animated at all. There's a similar Github Issue here, so I tried that since it got solved.

But that still doesn't seem to be working as I'm getting this https://jsfiddle.net/m1og17yz/2/ as you can see there is a delay between ending of the drawing and the filling.

```
callback: function (obj) {
     obj.el.classList.add('finished');
}
```

Comment: I will publish a new version asap. @Harti created a GitHub issue for this which I will be looking into. https://github.com/innovato/fontanimate/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

The commit that added the callback **was not released** on NPM.
So we both ended up installing an old version of the library that does not contain the code that passes the callback.

Try `npm install innovato/fontanimate#master --save`.